# Button click event to transfer image between 2 Picturebox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

There are 25 Pictureboxes containing different image. User can click on the anyone of the pictureboxes and the image will be shown at the confirmation picturebox as a final decision to proceed.
The code I apply on here is `PictureBoxConfirmation.Image = My.Resources._XX` (XX will be 1-25 in number respectively.). Later on, I will present a cofirmation button for the user to finalize their decision, and the chosen image will be locked in PictureBoxFinal.

The problem is I can't implement the `PictureBoxFinal.Image = My.Resources._XX` anymore since the selection will be on randomize input by user. So, how do I code for the button  to utilize this functionality. I had tried to put a tag for the PictureBoxConfirmaton when the image is being inserted to it. But, after that I am stuck. I Googled everything but still no result could help my situation.

Comment: You need to create a Event listener for the clic in all your PictureBoxes (this is a method/function that listen all you selectable pictureboxes). Inside the method, you get the Image from the clicked picturebox... and assign it to the PictureBoxFinal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Event listener for the clik in all your PictureBoxes (this is a method/function that listen all you selectable pictureboxes). Inside the method, you get the Image from the clicked picturebox... and assign it to the PictureBoxFinal one.

**To add the handler for the Click in all PictureBoxes:**

```
AddHandler PictureBox1.Click, AddressOf pic_Click
AddHandler PictureBox2.Click, AddressOf pic_Click
AddHandler PictureBox3.Click, AddressOf pic_Click
...
```

**The method that does the magic:**

```
Private Sub pic_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim picClicked As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    PictureBoxFinal.Image = picClicked.Image
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me digest it first, this is so next level for me. Thanks for your quick response! Do i have any way to commend your kindness in this website? sorry im new to this website too

Comment: hehe... this is quite basic... but from here you will learn the basics for handling user actions on your controls. If you thinks the answers you got are OK, you ACCEPT the response... or you can vote for the responses (to say that it helped you).